# Get rid of duplicate Strings in Java

Tags: java, filter

I have a String array:

```
String[] array = {"the","juice"};
```

and another String with some text:

```
String text = "the juice we had yesterday was great!";
```

and a function that basically checks if the words on the array exist in the text, and prints the string if that's the case.

This is pretty straightforward, however i get duplicate lines on the output, since the for loop checks for one word at a time. Since both exist in the string, the text will get printed twice.

Here's my code for illustrative purposes:

```
public void filter (String[] words, String text){

    for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++){

          if(text.toLowerCase().contains(words[i].toLowerCase()))

              System.out.println(text);

        }

}
```

How can i fix this ?

The proper output would be JUST ONE print of the line.

UPDATE:

Consider a text file being read instead of just a string:

```
public void filter (String[] words, BufferedReader text){

    String line = text.readLine();

    for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++){

          if(line.toLowerCase().contains(words[i].toLowerCase()))

              System.out.println(text);

        }
    line = text.readLine();
}
```

Comment: Don't you think about simple `return` when first occurence found?

Comment: Do you want to print only if all words in the array exist in the String or if any of the words are found?

Comment: Not clear enough. Do you want to print only if ALL the words in the array are present in your text?. Or print once you have found a match?

Comment: @Andremoniy yes, but for multiple lines of text, for example, from a file that does not work

Comment: @laker001 oh really? I don't believe, search for a mistake in your logic

Comment: @nomis updated since the example was not helpful

Comment: use line.toLowerCase() not text.toLowerCase()

Comment: So are you looking for the words[] array to be ANYWHERE in the File text?

Comment: @gtgaxiola exactly, and then print the lines where those words are included, but not all the words, i mean, if a sentence contains both or just one of the words, it should be printed out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit Answer as per  question change**

Goes over each line in the `reader`

Loops over the `words` array to find `any` Match

If match Print the text

Move on to the next line in the `reader`

```
public void filter(String[] words, BufferedReader reader) throws IOException {

    String text;
    while ((text = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            if (text.toLowerCase().contains(words[i].toLowerCase())) {
                //Anytime I'm able to find something ono the array print it out
                System.out.println(text);
                //move on to the next line in the reader
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it works now! but instead of the break line, i put text = reader.readLine();

Comment: @laker001 I would not recommend adding an extra reader.readLine()... The while loop will take care of reading line by line. The break is in order to avoid continuing checking for words on the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `break` into your `if` statement to stop your `for` loop from going any further.

```
public void filter (String[] words, String text){

    for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++){

          if(text.toLowerCase().contains(words[i].toLowerCase())){
              System.out.println(text);
              break; //this will stop processing your for loop
          }
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to add the braces for the `if` statement, else you'll break from the `for` loop after the first iteration.

Comment: You should fix the indentation, then you will see, why your current code won't work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `break` statement after `System.out.println(text);` to exit the `for` loop. However, you will need to use braces, else you will break from the `for` loop after the first iteration.

```
public void filter (String[] words, String text) {
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        if(text.toLowerCase().contains(words[i].toLowerCase())) {
            System.out.println(text);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

In your case, I would advise against using a `for` loop though, a `do/while` or a simple `while` would be more appropriate.